# IsVisible true afterNavigation.PopModalAsync();

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page that calls `PopModalAsync` on itself and, after it's disappeared from the screen, it's `IsVisible` property remains true.

Shouldn't it be false?

So, in the top level page is a property...

```
NavigationPage loginPage;
```

It's assigned in this method...

```
void HandleLogOut()
{
  authService.Logout();

  if (!(loginPage?.IsVisible ?? false))
            {
                loginPage = new NavigationPage(App.Container.Resolve<Login>());

                Navigation.PushModalAsync(loginPage);
            }
        }
```

The login page closes itself like this...

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

... and `IsVisible` remains true.

Comment: Can you share some code? Did you check all platforms?

Comment: I've posted some code. No, I've only tried on iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work...

```
loginPage.Disappearing += (sender, e) =>
{
   loginPage = null;
};
```